# Python turtle won't create multiple squares

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I tried to play around with this code many times but I can't create multiple squares. This is the problem:

Write a function named drawSquares that calls drawSquare to draw a
specified number of squares.
The function drawSquares takes four parameters: a turtle t, an integer size, an integer num, the number of squares to draw, and an integer angle, the clockwise rotation between successive squares

For example, the following would be
correct output.

import turtle

s = turtle.Screen()

snapper = turtle.Turtle()

drawSquares(snapper, 100, 4, 20)

```
import turtle

s = turtle.Screen()
t = turtle.Turtle()

def drawSquares(t, size, num, angle):

for i in range(num):
    for x in range(num):
        t.forward(size)
        t.right(angle)

t.forward(size)

drawSquares(t, 100, 4, 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this code should do exactly what you want:

```
import turtle

s = turtle.Screen()
t = turtle.Turtle()

def drawSquares(t, size, num, angle):

    for i in range(num):
        for x in range(4):
            turtle.forward(size)
            turtle.left(90)
        turtle.right(angle)

drawSquares(t, 100, 4, 20)
```

Comment: Yes that definitely worked. I tried putting the repetitive code in a for loop but that didn't work. I tried making a nested loop but it gave me the same output as when I first started. In what ways can I put this is in a loop? (turtle.forward(90), turtle.left(90), and turtle.right(angle)

Comment: @Gabriel sorry I don't understand you. What is the problem with my code?